# Expo does not start after system restarts

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I have an Expo project and it does not `expo start` whenever I close the project, shut down the system and restart the next day.

Everytime I try to execute `expo start`, I get a different error and the solution ends up being the same:

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm i`
3. `watchman watch-del-all`

Its fine for a couple of times but its become tedious to do this every time I start the project.

Error example :

`internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
throw err;`

Another error example:

[image: Error Example Image]

The errors are not consistent too, i.e., I could get different errors each day.

So, the question is - how do I fix this once and for all? Or how do I determine the root cause of the problem so I can fix this up>

Comment: My first guess is maybe it has something to do with paths? When I first started playing with expo and react-native I stopped doing global installs and instead used `npx expo start` to use the local node-modules, or change the PATH to point to your project node-modules.

Comment: Running `npx expo start` shows `Cannot find module 'cross-spawn'`